# Date subtraction in FlexibleSerchQuery

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to write a FlexibleSearchQuery to find records that are older than 30 days in hybris connected to a hsqldb database but the below code throws a

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data types in combination
```

Query:

```
final FlexibleSearchQuery flexibleSearchQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery("
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER AS c WHERE c.timestamp < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30")
```

Could someone please advice on how to fix this issue ?

Comment: I would suggest not use DB specific function, as many times local setup has different DB setup then production and we end up with such error. Instead, pass java date object to your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+1 to HybrisHelp answer. You should calculate the date and pass it on to flexible query.

A shorter version of same using Java 8 time api.

```
final FlexibleSearchQuery flexibleSearchQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery("
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER AS c WHERE c.timestamp < ?inputDate")

flexibleSearchQuery.addQueryParameter("inputDate", 
                              new DateTime(Instant.now()).minusDays(30).toDate());
```

Answer (score 3):

I would rather pass `java.util.Date` object to Flexible query like this

```
//Import statement
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;

//Flexible search query 
final FlexibleSearchQuery flexibleSearchQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(" SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER AS c WHERE c.timestamp < ?days")
flexibleSearchQuery.addQueryParameter("days", substractDaysFromDate(30));
flexibleSearchService.search(flexibleSearchQuery);

//method to get date difference
private Date subtractDaysFromCurrentDate(int days)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -days);
    cal = DateUtils.truncate(cal, Calendar.DATE);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        final String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM {Customer} AS c WHERE c.timestamp < ?date";

        final Map<String, Date> queryMap = new HashMap<String, Date>();
        queryMap.put("date", DateUtils.addDays(new Date(),-30));
        final SearchResult<CustomerModel> results = flexibleSearchService.search(QUERY , queryMap);
        return results.getResult();
```